# Randomization scheme for rating images and assessing inter-rater reliability

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, agreement-statistics, random-allocation

Apologies for the basic question, but I'm new to the area and I'm working on a research project on rating images, and assessing the reliability of these ratings, with the following structure:

There are 973 images, each of which has to be rated 3 times. These 2919 total ratings are to be allocated as evenly as possible between 5 raters (e.g., so that a rater is unlikely to rate the same image 3 times). Each rater will rate the "goodness" of their images on a 3-point scale ("Pass", "Maybe", "Fail"). Finally, we also want to assess the inter-rater reliability of the ratings.

If anyone knows of (and how to implement) a good (or, better yet, optimal) randomization scheme to allocate the images to the raters in a way that would facilitate the assessment of the reliability of the ratings, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate inter-rater reliability, you should prevent each individual rater from assigning multiple ratings to the same image.  That is, each image should be rated by three *different* raters. Aside from that, any randomization scheme would be fine. Maybe try to ensure that all five raters end up rating similar numbers of images (e.g., $2919/5=583.8$).

Also, be sure to use a formulation of agreement that allows for multiple, different raters. A generalized formula for agreement, Fleiss' kappa coefficient, or Bennett et al.'s S score with ordinal weights would work well.